# How to filter and get folder with latest date in google dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am passing in an wilcard match string as gs://dev-test/dev_decisions-2018-11-13*/. And i am passing to TextIO as below.

`p.apply(TextIO.read().from(options.getLocalDate()))`

Now i want to read all folders from the bucket named dev-test and filter and only read files from the latest folder. Each folder has a name with timestamp appended to it.

I am new to dataflow and not sure how would I go about doing this.

Comment: It isn't clear.  Do you have a bucket containing dated files or a bucket containing dated folders?  You said "... read files from the latest bucket".  Did you mean bucket or folder?  If folder, how is the concept of "latest folder" defined?  The date/time that the folder was created or its name?

Comment: I have a bucket containing different folders which have name + appended timestamp. For a particular day need to only pick latest folder available and read all files inside it

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JavaDoc [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.8.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.Read.html#from-java.lang.String-) it seems as though we can code:

```
String folder = // The GS path to the latest/desired folder.
PCollection<String> myPcollection = p.apply(TextIO.Read.from(folder+"/*")
```

The resulting PCollection will thus contain all the text lines from *all* the files in the specified folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can have multiple folders in the same bucket with the same date prefix/suffix as for example "data-2018-12-18_part1", "data-2018-12-18_part2" etc, the following will work. Its a python example but it works for Java as well. You will just need to get the date formatted as per your folder name and construct the path accordingly.

```
# defining the input path pattern 
input = 'gs://MYBUCKET/data-' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '*\*'
(p
      | 'ReadFile' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input)
...
...
```

it will read all the files from all the folders matching the pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the most recent folder will always be today's date, you could use a literal string as in [Tanveer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53823391/1260237). If you don't know that and need to filter the actual folder names for the most recent date, I think you'll need to use [`FileIO.match`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.9.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html#match--) to read file and directory names, and then collect them all to one node in order to do figure out which is the most recent folder, then pass that folder name into `TextIO.read().from()`.

The filtering might look something like:

```
ReduceByKey.of(FileIO.match("mypath"))
            .keyBy(e -> 1) // constant key to get everything to one node
            .valueBy(e -> e)
            .reduceBy(s -> ???) // your code for finding the newest folder goes here
            .windowBy(new GlobalWindows())
            .triggeredBy(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow())
            .discardingFiredPanes()
            .output()
```

Comment: Thinking about this more, I think you'd be better off using Beam's `Filesystems` API directly to get the file list on a single node: `Filesystems.match("gs://mybucket/*")`. Filter those results locally to find the folder you want, then pass that into `TextIO.read().from()`. I expect that will be much simpler and more readable than the ReduceByKey above.